# Why does "та ночь" become "ту ночью", in "I saw a cat, that night"?

Tags: окончания

Somebody told to me that "I saw a cat, that night" translated to "я видел кошку, ту **ночью**", but I do not understand why "**ночь**" becomes **ночью**

Answer (score 4):

"Ту ночью" is ungrammatical. It should be either **той ночью** or **в ту ночь**. And no comma is needed. And it's more natural to put it before **я видел кошку**. Or, more colloquially, between **я** and **видел**.

Answer (score 2):

Mentioning a period of time when something is happening you have to use `творительный падеж`. "Ночью" is that form of "ночь".

Other examples:

- Я работаю днём ("днём" - творительный падеж от "день")
- Мы встретились вечером ("вечером" - творительный падеж от "вечер")
- Зимой у нас очень холодно ("зимой" - творительный падеж от "зима")

Answer (score 1):

The instrumental case is used when something happens during one of the following periods of time: утро, день, вечер, ночь, зима, весна, лето, осень.  Examples:

- Прошлой весной мне исполнилось четыре года. (Last spring I turned 4 years old.)
- Зимой я выхожу на пенсию. (This winter I retire from work.)
- Ночью надо спать, а не дрочить. (At night you/one should sleep, not masturbate.)
- Есть ночью вредно. (It is unhealthy to eat at night.)

You cannot do this with other time intervals.  The following examples are WRONG!

- Прошлой средой Маша ездила в ресторан с друзьями и ужралась в хлам. (Correctly: в прошлую среду Маша ездила в ресторан с друзьями и ужралась в хлам.  "Ужралась в хлам" is a colloquial phrase meaing "got very drunk".)
- Следующим годом я научусь правильно говорить по-русски. (Correctly: в следующем году я научусь правильно говорить по-русски.)